# jquery popup activated on hover over <a> need to change to <label>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, label

I have a popup system that shows a image when you hover over a link. Instead I need the popup to be activated when you hover over `<label>`

popup.js

```
/*
 * Url preview script 
 * powered by jQuery (http://www.jquery.com)
 * 
 * written by Alen Grakalic (http://cssglobe.com)
 * 
 * for more info visit http://cssglobe.com/post/1695/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery
 *
 */

this.screenshotPreview = function(){    
    /* CONFIG */

        xOffset = 130;
        yOffset = 60;

        // these 2 variable determine popup's distance from the cursor
        // you might want to adjust to get the right result

    /* END CONFIG */
    $("a.screenshot").hover(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";    
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br/>" + this.t : "";
        $("body").append("<p id='screenshot'><img src='"+ this.rel +"' alt='image loading...' />"+ c +"</p>");                               
        $("#screenshot")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn("fast");                        
    },
    function(){
        this.title = this.t;    
        $("#screenshot").remove();
    }); 
    $("a.screenshot").mousemove(function(e){
        $("#screenshot")
            .css("top",(e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left",(e.pageX + yOffset) + "px");
    });         
};


// starting the script on page load
$(document).ready(function(){
    screenshotPreview();
});
```

Here is the html that activate the popup

HTML:

```
<a style="" class="screenshot" rel="images/0.jpg" title="blablabla">blablabla</a>
```

I tried:

`<label for="0" class="screenshot" rel="images/0.jpg" title="blablabla">blablabla</label>`and changed to this in the js `$("label.screenshot").hover`, but I only get image loading and no image..

Comment: Did it work when it was a link? Did you inspect the image path and make sure it is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having, is that since `this.rel` is accessing the dom property `rel` which is a properly of a `a` tag but not a property of a `label`.

Change your code to `$(this).attr('rel')`, so it will pickup the **attribute**.

```
$("body").append("<p id='screenshot'><img src='"+ $(this).attr('rel') ...
```